# Are Mac OS X services name sensitive?

Tags: applescript, automator, services

Are Mac OS X services name sensitive?  I have the following Applescript code and can install it as a service (using Automator) with the name "Move_Mail_L5", but can't install it as a service with the name "Move_Mail_LV".

```
on run {input, parameters}
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Mail"
            click menu item "Landscaping V" of menu 1 of menu item "Move to" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Message" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

My four files in ~/Library/Services are

```
Move_Mail_L5.workflow
Copy_Mail_LV.workflow
Copy_Mail_BC.workflow
Move_Mail_BC.workflow
```

There is no naming problem with "Copy_Mail_LV.workflow".  Its code is the same as that of "Move_Mail_L5.workflow", except that it has "Copy" in place of "Move".

My Mac Book Air 2012 is running Sierra version 10.12.6

Added later: I can install it with the name "Mov_Mail_LV".

Comment: I had no problem saving it as an Automator Service named: Move_Mail_LV

Comment: Was there ever a file in there named Move_Mail_LV? It might be worth rebooting and resetting your PRAM - sometimes when I have this issue it’s because the system thinks the file is still there when it clearly isn’t.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion to do a NVRAM reset seems to have fixed the naming problem that I had described.  After doing a NVRAM reset I could name the service as "Move_Mail_LV"--as desired.